# Duplicated packages in vendor.js with laravel mix

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-mix, laravel-mix-vue3

I have a local npm package, that contains other local npm packages

[image]

All of these packages are very similar, all uses vue, jquery, etc.

When i compile:

```
mix.js('index.js','dist/app.js').vue().extract();
```

The bundler analyzer shows in the vendor.js that every package contains its own node_modules and contains many packages duplicated.

How can avoid this?

[image]